# Conditional Symbols in Highcharts

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am trying to create a line chart which shows internet usage per day for a certain number of machines. I want to use a symbol as shown [here in Highcharts documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-symbols) whenever a certain data limit is exceeded. For example, where ever the usage is above 2.5 GB,I want it to show an Alert Symbol and above 3 GB some other symbol. Values lower than those should be shown by normal markers. These values will be fetched from dynamically created CSV files so I can not hard-code them as told in documentation. Need to give a condition where the marker will be replaced by symbol automatically if the condition is met. How can I achieve this?

The following is my series data

```
   series: [{
        name: '<Machine Ip>',
        data: [1.60, 3.60, 1.70, 2.70, 0.40]
    }, {
        name: '<Machine Ip>',
        data: [0.20, 3.40, 2.10, 2.30, 1.40]
    }, {
        name: '<Machine Ip>',
        data: [2.20, 1.40, 2.80, 0.60, 2.80]
    }]
```

I am sorry I can't share other code due to confidentiality reasons. I have not applied any logic so far as I have not been able to conjure up any. The Machine IP is dynamically obtained from values passed from earlier page. There is a variable in that place. Just replaced that by `<machine ip>` to make it clear.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you paste you series data here and the code you have done so far?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of updating, you can preprocess you data after you receive CSV, demo: http://jsfiddle.net/grLf9jn0/

Snippet:

```
$.each(parsedDataFromCSV, function (i, v) {
    parsedDataFromCSV[i] = {
        y: v,
        marker: v > 15 ? {
            symbol: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/snow.png)'
        } : (v > 10 ? {
            symbol: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png)'
        } : {})
    };
});
```

Or event **better**: when you parse your data from CSV to JS objects, add conditions to set marker there.

**Edit:**

When using data.js module, use `data.complete` callback, like this:

```
    data: {
        csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML,
        complete: function (options) {
            $.each(options.series, function(j, series) {
                $.each(series.data, function(i, v) {
                  series.data[i] = {
                    y: v[1],
                    x: v[0],
                    marker: v[1] > 0.5 ? {
                        symbol: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/snow.png)'
                    } : (v[1] < 0 ? {
                        symbol: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png)'
                    } : {})
                  };
                });
            });
        }
    },
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mjjoyw94/1/

Comment: Actually I was hoping to import data using this way explained in Highcharts documentation [link](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-module)

Comment: HI, tired using this with csv file, but the chart lines won't get plotted at all.. Only the axes got plotted.

Comment: Any errors? Or could you show CSV sample? Maybe you have different format for CSV, not like the one I used. Does even it work for you when removing "complete" part?

Comment: Mine is a local CSV file, so I am fetching it and not reading it from within HTML itself. You can find the image here: http://postimg.org/image/ahpraytnb/

Comment: Also I am not being able to link my CSV file in JSfiddle. I have made a temporary fiddle for you. It is at https://jsfiddle.net/xoaqgubv/6/ However because it is not able to fetch the CSV, it is giving a blank output. The CSV is uploaded at http://tempsend.com/3CDA19F2E1 and the file is valid for one day. I have used the same url in JSFiddle but maybe my syntax is wrong. Please do help

Comment: Twi things with tempsend: 1) Path is wrong. 2) You can not load load sources because of CORS. If you enable CORS (by some Chrome plugin or by flag), then this should work for you: http://jsfiddle.net/xoaqgubv/8/ Also, when working on a local files, CORS won't allow you to load data from filesystem, you need some simple server.  And example without AJAX: http://jsfiddle.net/mjjoyw94/3/

Comment: Yeah, using flags worked.. However it is still working on only one series. Check this out: http://uploadpie.com/ZglRj

Comment: See updated `edit` part - loop over all series the same way as you do for points.

Comment: Still, only one line is getting conditional symbols

Comment: Right my mistake. You can try to fix my code, you know that? ;) See working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mjjoyw94/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the callback argument of `highcharts()` function to update each points depending on its value. I have made an example on a temperature chart, JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qot0pjhp/

Important part of the code is:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    /* ... */,
    function (chart) {
        $.each(chart.series[0].points, function (i, v) {
            if (v.y >= 25) {
                v.update({
                    marker: {
                        symbol: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png)'
                    }
                })
            } else if (v.y >= 15) {
                v.update({
                    marker: {
                        symbol: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/snow.png)'
                    }
                })
            }
        });
    });
```

So here each point above 25 will have a sun as marker, each point above 15 will have a snow cloud, and every other points will have the marker defined in `plotOptions`.

**EDIT**

If you have multiple series, you can just modify it to:

```
function (chart) {
     $.each(chart.series, function(index, serie_item) {
          $.each(serie_item.points, function (i, v) {
              /* ... */
          });
     });
});
```

Comment: Looks awesome. Let me try this out

Comment: @ashhem The solution PawelFus provides might be better as it does not update the chart after load.

Comment: I tried this, Working fine. The issue is I need to fetch data from a CSV file and has multiple series. I am not being able to apply this solution to my case. Can you please help?

Comment: You can apply it to each series with another loop. See the edit.